# Technique Interview's Vocabulary

Tags: hiring-process

I am from Argentina and I believe I have a good english level. These days I'll be having an interview through skype where they will test my english... The thing is I don't fear talking in english about my personal life and the things I love to do but I do fear If I have to talk a more technic english... As I don't have certain words "in my mind"...

The thing I would like is: To list verbs or things I could be ask... For example: If I have an scrum meeting, things I could say... Could that be possible guys ?.
Thankx

Comment: Why not just answer the call in English?  If you have good conversational English then it will come out.

Comment: Are you asking us to make a list of possible questions for you? And then to provide possible answers for you? This might be a good preparation exercise, but one that you should do on your own. I would prefer to do it with pen and paper, and to practice a little and think through some scenarios. But in the end it will be up to the interviewer what actually gets asked.

Comment: " I believe I have a good english level" - I'm not sure how to put this politely...

Answer (score 2):

This one is pretty open ended as is.  We usually don't use this forum to address the skills of a specific job.

With that said, my recommendation would be to dig through English-based stack exchanges for topics relevant to your work.  For example, if you are concerned about what you'd say during a scrum, see if you can find some threads on Stack Overflow or Programmers on the challenges of daily scrums and how people talk about them.  If you are concerned about communicating about a particular type of development, dig into the topic and uncover the technical terms.  Also - read through the English wikipedia on these topics and follow through on terms you don't understand.

I don't think you want to be able to repeat key phrases that aren't in your words, it won't help when you encounter a problem on the job.

That said - having interviewed non-native English speakers - I'm less interested in giving them a vocabulary test, and more interested in knowing that when problems come up, my team will be able to work together through language challenges.  In my mind it would be fine for you to say "I do have daily meetings with my team where everyone quickly goes through what they are doing, and what help is needed" without you ever having to know that US tech workers call that a "stand-up" or a "scrum".  I also would want to know that if I threw out some word the interviewee didn't recognize that he'd politely stop me and make sure we agreed on a clear definition rather than just nod and try to guess at it.

I know that this definitely hits on cultural norms.  I happen to be a US based manager on the East Coast.  And I manage a team of people from at least 6 different places around the world (all of them are currently living in Boston but only two of us were born in the US).  My expectations are aligned with that... mileage will vary based on the location of the English speaking group you interview with and also how culturally aware they are.

Comment: +1, especially the last paragraph. I think reactions to this would vary greatly based on how much exposure to non-native speakers they have. Having worked a fair bit with international teams it wouldn't bother me at all as I can already "translate" non-native English somewhat. Missing specific words? Not a problem if you can still talk about the subjects well. Given the OP said the interview was to test their English, I suspect it's more of a "can you have a conversation in English well" type of interview more than anything else, which is hard to know how the interviewer will handle it..

Answer (score 2):

Write a script for yourself.

Most interviewers ask canned questions that you can find on any website.

- Biggest strength/flaw
- Mistake and how you fixed it
- Tell me about a challenge you had to overcome
- Your biggest/most important/most stressful project

If you're not confident simply make a list of the things you want to bring up, and practice those lines.

Also, print them in large font, so that if you panic and can't remember something you will have it right in front of you at a glance.

Comment: Print them in large font? For writing a script like this, it's better to write it on paper using your own hand. The slowness and deliberateness of this approach may help you learn it.

Comment: @Brandin - could we maybe agree that this might be a case for "to each his own"? Right. Great. Thanks.

Comment: No, it's a case of "here is a suggestion". Readers can take from it what they will. Printing is great for producing nice looking looking text. Writing longhand is good for concentration and committing to memory.

Answer (score 0):

You would know better what is applicable to your potential job than us. When I'm working in another language my strategy is simple.

I have a bunch of technical terms printed out and stuck to the wall as memory aids and reference, I used to do the same thing when studying different languages. After a while these become embedded in my mind and I add to them when I come across something interesting.

So make a list that is relevant to your work and print or write it out and stick it on the wall where you can't help but read it every so often.

Comment: Kilisi. Thank you very much for your answer... I'll have to make a list since the interview is tomorrow... For example: We often use the word "desplegar" in my work, but If I don't know that this is what we would call "deploy" I will get stuck... So yeah... I'll make that list...